# Making jQuery plugin exhibit jQuery's on() quality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just created a jQuery plugin http://jsbin.com/aCoboQo/2 which applies a tooltip to the selected elements.  To apply it to all elements of class "myElement", one would simply use the following script: `$('.myElement').toolTip();`

All is good until I wish to add another element.  The newly added element never had the plugin applied to it, so it will obviously not have a tooltip.  Yes, I know I can apply the tooltip to the newly added element after adding it, but I would rather not make the user need to.

How do I make my jQuery plugin exhibit jQuery's `on()` quality?  I am okay with either modifying the plugin or changing how I apply pluging.  As for what I mean about `on()` quality, something like `$('#myDiv').on('click','p.myElement',function(){alert('Hello');});`, but I don't want to force the user to always need to put some sort of `#myDiv` wrapper always around the elements in question.

Again, a live demo is at http://jsbin.com/aCoboQo/2 and the script is duplicated below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
        <title>screenshot</title>  
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <style type="text/css">

            .myElement{margin:100px;}
            .toolToolActive{color:blue;}

            .myTooTip {
                border:1px solid #CECECE;
                background:white;
                padding:10px;
                display:none;
                color:black;
                font-size:11px;-moz-border-radius:4px;
                box-shadow: 3px 1px 6px #505050;
                -khtml-border-radius:4px;
                -webkit-border-radius:4px;
                border-radius:4px;
            }
        </style> 

        <script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    var defaults = {
        'class'    : '', // Css class(es) to add to tooltip (along with standardToolTip).
        'mouseMove': true, // A flag indicating whether to move tooltip with mouse.
        'speed'    : 'fast', // The speed at which to fade in the tool tip.
        'delay'    : 250, // Delay (in ms) before opening the popup.
        'xOffset'  : 20,
        'yOffset'  : 10
    };

    var methods = {
        init : function (options) {
            // Create settings using the defaults extended with any options provided.
            var settings = $.extend(defaults, options  || {});

            return this.each(function () {
                var title,
                timeoutID,
                $t,
                toolTip;

                // Wrap the content of the current element in a span.
                $t = $(this).wrapInner('<span />');

                $t.children('span').hover(function(e) {
                    if(!$t.hasClass('toolToolActive')) {
                        title = $t.attr('title');
                        $t.attr('title','');  // Remove the title so that it doesn't show on hover.

                        timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function () {
                            // Create a div to be the tooltip pop up, add the styling as well as
                            // the html (from the display function) to it and then fade the element in
                            // using the speed specified in the settings.
                            toolTip = $('<div />')
                            .addClass('standardToolTip ' + settings['class'])
                            .html(title)
                            .css('top', (e.pageY - settings.yOffset) + 'px')
                            .css('left', (e.pageX + settings.xOffset) + 'px')
                            .css('position', 'absolute')
                            .appendTo('body')
                            .fadeIn(settings.speed);

                            $t.addClass('toolToolActive');

                            }, settings.delay);
                    }
                    },
                    function () {
                        window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
                        $t.attr('title', title);

                        if ($t.hasClass('toolToolActive')) {
                            toolTip.remove();
                            $t.removeClass('toolToolActive');
                        }
                });

                $t.mousemove(function (e) {
                    if (settings.mouseMove && $t.hasClass('toolToolActive')) {
                        toolTip.css('top', (e.pageY - settings.yOffset) + 'px')
                        .css('left', (e.pageX + settings.xOffset) + 'px');
                    }
                });
            });
        },
        destroy : function () {
            return this.each(function () {
                var $e = $(this);
                $e.html($e.children('span').html());
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn.toolTip = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.toolTip');
        }    
    };
    }(jQuery));
          $(function(){
                $('.myElement').toolTip({
                    'class':'myTooTip'
                });
                 $('.add').click(function(){$('#myDiv').append('<p class="myElement" data-id="4" title="Popup for New Doe">New Doe</p>');});
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="myDiv">
          <p class="myElement" data-id="1" title="Popup for John Doe">John Doe</p>
        <p class="myElement" data-id="2" title="Popup for Jane Doe">Jane Doe</p>
        <p class="myElement" data-id="3" title="Popup for Baby Doe">Baby Doe</p>
      </div>
        <p class="add">Add</p>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: The `.on()` function takes advantage of the event bubbling behavior that browsers do naturally. You could take advantage of the events generated when the DOM is modified, like [the x-tag project](http://www.x-tags.org/) does.

Comment: @Pointy.  Please elaborate.

Comment: In plain English ..the on() function actually does nothing more than monitor ALL clicks (or other types of events) on the ``document`` and then checks if the element you clicked on matches a particular pattern

Comment: @Robert.  Doesn't seem very efficient.  Maybe I am better served by manually applying the event to the added elements right after I add them?

Comment: There are [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Mutation_events) fired when the DOM is modified, but they're problematic.

Comment: @Pointy.  Yikes, mutations!  Is it fair to say that plugins are not typically designed to automatically respond to changes in DOM?

Comment: Yes, that's fair to say.

Comment: As for twitter boostrap tooltip, you should use delegation. You could check bootstrap tooltip source code and see how they delegate tooltip plugin using 'selector' option.

Comment: Could be a starter: http://jsbin.com/aCoboQo/3

Comment: @A.Wolff.  Seems more that just a starter.  Do you see any problems for doing it this way?

Comment: I don't see any problem but that doesn't means there is no problem. It is the logic used by twitter bootstrap tooltip. When i said starter, i mean you need to do test and see if it fit your needs. You coud wish to pass instead options to your plugin to enable or not this 'delegation' and to apply to specific elements only. BTW, on jsbin i use selector property of jquery object which is deprecated http://api.jquery.com/selector/ Using a selector as option of plugin as in bootstrap would be better.